# Nested loop not appending when generating sub menus

Tags: jquery, loops

I asked a question [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57680/improving-nested-for-loops-for-sub-menu-creation) on code review, but cant seem to integrate the answer into my code.

The first level of the drop down works fine so it shows the publishers as expected, but with this code the authors arent appended and not sure why.

Here's the snippet in question:

```
if (typeof app.cache.publisher[publisherval].author[authorval] == 'undefined') {
app.cache.publisher[publisherval].author[authorval] = $('<li class="author" data-value="' + authorval + '"><a href="#" class="nextmenu">' + authorval + '</a><ul class="sub-menu" data-title="authors"></ul></li>').children('ul').appendTo(ulauthors);
}
```

Here's the full code:

```
function createDropDown() {
        var target = $('#dropdownMenu');
        for (var i = 0; i < data.genres.length; i++) {
                var genreval = data.genres[i].genre;
                for (var j = 0; j < data.genres[i].publishers.length; j++) {
                        var publisherval = data.genres[i].publishers[j].publisher;
                        if (typeof app.cache.publisher[publisherval] == 'undefined') {
                                target.append('<li class="publisher" data-value="' + publisherval + '"><a href="#" class="nextmenu">' + publisherval + '</a><ul class="sub-menu" data-title="publishers"></ul></li>');
                                app.cache.publisher[publisherval] = {
                                        'ul': target.find('>.publisher[data-value="' + publisherval + '"]>.sub-menu'),
                                        'author': {}
                                };
                        }
                        var ulauthors = app.cache.publisher[publisherval].ul;
                        for (var k = 0; k < data.genres[i].publishers[j].authors.length; k++) {
                                var authorval = data.genres[i].publishers[j].authors[k].author + ' (' + genreval + ')';
                                var author_val = data.genres[i].publishers[j].authors[k].author;
                                var originalgenre = data.genres[i].publishers[j].authors[k].originalgenre;
                                if (typeof app.cache.publisher[publisherval].author[authorval] == 'undefined') {
                                        ulauthors.append('<li class="author" data-value="' + authorval + '"><a href="#" class="nextmenu">' + authorval + '</a><ul class="sub-menu" data-title="authors"></ul></li>');
                                        app.cache.publisher[publisherval].author[authorval] = ulauthors.find('>.author[data-value="' + authorval + '"]>.sub-menu');
                                }
                                var ulyears = app.cache.publisher[publisherval].author[authorval];
                                var gItems = "";
                                for (var m = 0; m < data.genres[i].publishers[j].authors[k].authorYears.length; m++) {
                                        var yearval = data.genres[i].publishers[j].authors[k].authorYears[m];
                                        var year = ulyears.find('.year[data-value="' + yearval + '"]');
                                        if (year.size() == 0) {
                                                var id = ++count;
                                                gItems += '<li class="year" data-value="' + yearval + '"><a id="selyear' + id + '" class="addItem" data-id="' + id + '" data-originalgenre ="' + originalgenre + '"data-year="' + yearval + '" data-publisher="' + publisherval + '" data-author="' + author_val '">' + yearval + '</a></li>';
                                        }
                                }
                                ulyears.append(gItems);
                        };
                };
        };
}
```

The HTML is very basic, just:

```
<ul id="dropdownMenu" class="authordropdown">                                      </ul>
```

Which is populated through the JS.

Comment: Just a tip: split your function into smaller functions which would digest smaller pieces of data. E.g.  processGenre(data.genres[i].genre);

Comment: If you can create a fiddle, it will be really helpful

Comment: Hi, i can't create a fiddle unfortunately, running in IE8 (company restriction) thats the reason i'm trying to optimise for slow JS engine :(